# Resetting jquery varible to lowest possible value that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This script generate divs with cloud images that fly from left to right with random height and intervals. It generally works but it keeps incrementing divs "id" infinitely. I can't figure out how to reset the counter being safe that never two identical "id"s will exist in the same time.

```
function cloudgenerator(){

var nr=1;
var t1 = 20000;
var t2 = 50000;

function cloud(type,time,nr){
    $("#sky").append("<div id=\"cloudFL"+nr+"\" class=\"cloud"+type+"\" ></div>");
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#cloudFL"+nr).css({top:Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)+'px'}).animate({
                left:'100%',
                },time,'linear',function(){$(this).remove();
                });
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * t1));
}; 

function wave(){
    var tx = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        cloud(1,t1,nr);
        nr++;

        var n = $( "div.cloud1" ).length;
        $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n +" n and "+ tx +" tx")

        if(tx < n){tx = n}
        else(tx = 1)

        },500); 
};

wave()};

cloudgenerator()
```

In the bottom, there is an instruction that checks if number of divs is starting to drop and presents those values in span for debugging.

Comment: You don't need to put IDs on the clouds at all. Just save your generated element to a variable (`var el = $('<div class="cloud" ...></div>';`) and attach the required behavior to that (`el.css(...)...`).

Comment: I think I need IDs. There will be different things happening to individual clouds and groups of clouds. I need to find a specific one as long as its on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick and easy solution**
You could loop through the id's in JQuery, starting from the lowest number, until you find a JQuery selector that yields 0 results...

```
var newid = 0;
var i = 1;
while(newid == 0) {
    if( $('#cloudFL' + i).length == 0 ) { newid = i; }
    else { i++; }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/t0d5eu8j/)**

**Alternative solution** (scalable)
Given that you may have many clouds onscreen at one time, you could try this alternative approach.
This approach creates an array of 'used ids' and the wave function then checks if any 'used ids' are available before creating a new id for the cloud function. This will run quite a bit more efficiently that then above 'quick fix solution' in situations where many clouds appear on screen.

```
function cloudgenerator(){

var nr=1;
var t1 = 20000;
var t2 = 50000;
var spentids = [];

function cloud(type,time,id){
    $("body").append('<div id="' + id + '" class="cloud' + type + '" >' + id + '</div>');
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#'+id).css({top:Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)+'px'}).animate({
                left:'100%',
                },time,'linear',function(){
                    spentids.push( $(this).attr('id') );
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * t1));
}; 

function wave(){

    setInterval(function(){
        if(spentids.length == 0) {
            cloud(1,t1,"cloudFL" + nr);
            nr++;
        } else {
            spentids = spentids.sort();
            cloud(1,t1,spentids.shift());                
        }

        },500); 
};

wave()};

cloudgenerator()
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO - ALTERNATIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/2ptb30xd/)**

Comment: @user3540769 
out of curiosity, which solution did you end up implementing

Comment: Perfect. This array was great idea. I can use it for further modification. Also I love the how they fly with their tags showing ;). Here is the link http://cloudmedia.pl/. I'll need to add a  immediate first wave before setInterval kicks in.

Comment: I used alternative solution. I will need that array for later.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the timestamp and add this to your id?

If you don´t need the ids i would stick to @hon2a and just add the styling to the class and remove the ids.

And another solution:

You could make a check if ID xyz is used. Like this e.g.

```
  var cloudCount = jQuery('.cloud20000').length + jQuery('.cloud50000').length + 10;
  for(var i = 0; i <= cloudCount; i++) {
    if(jQuery('#cloudFL' + i).length <= 0) {
      nr = i;
      return false;
    }
  }

  cloud(1,t1,nr);
```

Comment: It was useful but I can't vote it up. It's my first post here I don't have reputation to do that. Also I need to store IDs to find them again later. Just started to use JQuery and I am having problems with switching my brain from php so its still hard for me to further develop your solution.